# How to deal with big data in Angular

Tags: javascript, angularjs, xmlhttprequest

I have a finished AngularJS app, which basically shows a table with many (400+) rows loaded via `$resources`. The data is sortable and searchable and the application is a bit slow loading (2s+) and yes, I used `$cacheFactory`. I thin, it's a RAM issue.

I thought of loading just 100 entries and reloading automatically after search, sort or scroll. This would speed up the app but make searches and sorts really slow.

How would you deal with this in Angular?

Comment: 400+ rows data grid is nothing.

Comment: You could us [AngularJS Batarang](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/angularjs-batarang/ighdmehidhipcmcojjgiloacoafjmpfk) to check is this is just an issue with displaying all the entries (most likely) or holding them in memory.

Comment: Assuming that you use `ng-repeat` to display the data, this question also might depend on the Angular.js version you are using. `ng-repeat` got a lot faster in 1.2. But you question is to vague, to actually give an answer.

Comment: There's more to this. How many columns are there? Are you including heavy DOM elements in the table (like checkboxes), and are you doing any further manipulation?

Comment: Depending on your situation, you may like this:  http://binarymuse.github.io/ngInfiniteScroll/

Comment: @TheHippo Thanks, I'll test this, love the extension. I use ng-repeat on version 1.2, so that won't be the problem.

Comment: @MikeRobinson About 8 columns with nothing but `spans` and one `button` per row, so nothing heavy. I'm doing no further manipulation.

Comment: @lucuma Thank you, bookmarked. If everything else fails, I'll use this!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to be very careful when deciding what data should be two way data bound when dealing with large data sets otherwise you will overwhelm the DOM and cpu with $watch expressions.

I've created a set of directives that bind data only once where needed.

here's a link to three I've made that should be helpful:

https://gist.github.com/btm1

set-attr - set any attribute on an element with an assigned value once and do not add a watch listener. U can use this to set classes or data attributes or IDs

set-if - use this instead of show or hide or switch. It's an if statement that evaluates only once and will remove items from the DOM

set-repeat - this one is awesome especially if what you're repeating through won't change so it will just iterate through something once.

I've created others that set-text, set-html, set-href, set-source, and i find i use them a lot because most data doesn't need to be two way data bound.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I will test the directives today or tomorrow. I wonder why Angular hasn't built them in.

Comment: np please vote up my answer if you find the helpful.